# DolphinDB Python API: Get the number of records queried by SQL statements

Tags: python, sql, select, dolphindb, rowcount

I run the following script in Python:

```
t2 = t1.select("count(*)")
t2.toDF()
```

Output (of DataFrame type):

```
   count
0  13136
```

If I run the script as follows:

```
t2.toDF().count # count is the column name corresponding to the result of count(*)
```

Output (of <class 'method'> data type):

```
<bound method DataFrame.count of    count
0  13136>
```

How to get the number of records of type scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1: use function [pandas.DataFrame.count](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html).

```
trade.select("*").toDF().count()["col"]
# col is the name of any column of the DataFrame returned by the SQL query
# Any SQL statement can be used before toDF()
```

Solution 2:

In DolphinDB, the output of `t2=t1.select("count(*)")` is stored in the “count“ column. `t2.toDF().count` does not return the result of the count column as there is a method count with the same name in pandas.DataFrame. It is recommended to specify aliases for the result columns returned by count(*).

```
t2 = t1.select("count(*) as cnt")
t2.toDF().cnt
```

Return a Seires. You can obtain the scalar with index.

```
t2.toDF().cnt[0]
```

See also: [DolphinDB Python API](https://github.com/dolphindb/api_python3/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 0):

The `toDF()` function returns a DataFrame, please try `t2.toDF()['count'][0]`.